# Two point measurement statistics in Quantum systems

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, probability, quantum-statistics, open-quantum-systems

I am reading a [paper](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevE.75.050102) related to fluctuations in Quantum thermodynamics. I am unable to understand the math behind equation no. 10 where the probability density function for work distribution is calculated. I can't understand how delta function is arising in the equation.
The same is also done in [another article](https://doi.org/10.1103/RevModPhys.81.1665). Can someone help me in understanding how is PDF constructed?
Eqn 10 looks like this(taken from [article](https://elib.uni-stuttgart.de/bitstream/11682/11295/1/main_for_library_a4.pdf)):
$$
P(Q, t)=\sum_{n, m} \delta\left[Q-\left(E_{m}-E_{n}\right)\right] P_{n \rightarrow m}^{\tau} P_{n}^{0}
$$
where we measure the system energy at the beginning of the process to find it in some state $|n\rangle$ with associated probability $P_{n}^{0}$ and again after some time $\tau=\gamma t$, which is rescaled with respect to the damping constant $\gamma$, to find it in a state $|m\rangle .$ The probability to move from the initial state $|n\rangle$ to the final state $|m\rangle$ is given by $P_{n \rightarrow m}^{\tau} .$

Comment: You should include the equations here, since not all members have accounts on Physical Review, and we try to avoid links as much as possible. Please use [Mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to enter mathematical 
equations and expressions.

Comment: What is $Q$ in this equation?

Comment: @LucasBaldo its heat distribution or work distribution

Answer (score 1):

The Delta function is constraining energy to be conserved.

The sum is over all transitions $n\rightarrow m$. However, the term $\delta[Q - (E_m - E_n)]$ is picking out only the terms where the heat generated ($Q$) is equal to the energy lost in the transition ($E_m - E_n$).